# any one can explain the Registration Service working at server in iOS for my website

Tags: ios, json

```
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.bikrionline.com/database/iqry_mbr_mst.php"]];
        // create the Method "GET" or "POST"

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        //Pass The String to server
    NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"txtemail=%@&txtpwd=%@&txtcpwd=%@", email, password,confirmpassword];

        //Check The Value what we passed
        NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

        //Convert the String to Data
        NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //Apply the data to the body
        [request setHTTPBody:data1];

        //Create the response and Error

        NSError *err;
        NSURLResponse *response;

        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&err];

        NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        //This is for Response 
        NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

        if(resSrt)
        {
//            NSLog(@"got response");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Registration" message:@"Congratulations you account has been created successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];


        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"faield to connect");
        }

}
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking .

Comment: explain the procedure for registration. how is it work.

Comment: Please do some research on this first. Your question is too broad.

Comment: actually i am asking the service for registration to my php developer. but he given some url . its not working. so he asking me what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may not be working because the URL you have given without HTTP try changing your code like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bikrionline.com/database/iqry_mbr_mst.php"]];
```

Comment: than you its working.

Comment: @veeresh give my answer right and vote it up